# Algebraic solution from system of symbolic equations for single variable

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have a mathematical system like

```
K_1 = c*h/d
K_2 = b*h/c
K_3 = a*h/b
C = a+b+c+d
h+d = W/h + b + 2a
Constants: K_1, K_2, K_3, C, W
Solve for: h, a,b,c,d
```

Is it possible to use Mathematica to generate a polynomial or other algebraic equation for one or each of the variables `h,a,b,c,d` in terms of constants `K_1, K_2, K_3, C, W` alone? (These will usually be fifth degree or above so we cannot solve for the variable directly in terms of the constants. A polynomial in that variable is the best we can do.)

Comment: Yes, it is possible, the unknown variables can be expressed in terms of constants using a 5th-order algebraic equation. Have a look at the syntax of `Solve`.

Comment: Are the constants reals? Do you know their values?

Comment: The constants are of unknown value and the solution I'm looking at would be symbolic so their values should not matter. (Not even the realness) Algebraic substitution would get me the solution by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the approaches by Daniel Huber and Roma Lee provides the desired answer more or less instantly.

```
eq = {K1 == c*h/d, K2 == b*h/c, K3 == a*h/b, C == a + b + c + d, h + d == W/h + b + 2 a};
sh = Solve[Eliminate[eq, {a, b, c, d}], h] // Flatten
(* {h -> Root[-K1 K2 K3 W + (-2 C K1 K2 K3 - K1 K2 W) #1 + (-C K1 K2 + 
    K1 K2 K3 - K1 W) #1^2 + (K1 K2 - W) #1^3 + (C + K1) #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1], ... *)
```

where " . . . " represents the other four roots.  Then, solve for the other variables.

```
sabcd = Solve[Most@eq, {a, b, c, d}] // Flatten
(* {a -> (C K1 K2 K3)/(h^3 + h^2 K1 + h K1 K2 + K1 K2 K3), 
    b -> (C h K1 K2)/(h^3 + h^2 K1 + h K1 K2 + K1 K2 K3), 
    c -> (C h^2 K1)/(h^3 + h^2 K1 + h K1 K2 + K1 K2 K3), 
    d -> (C h^3)/(h^3 + h^2 K1 + h K1 K2 + K1 K2 K3)} *)
```

producing the desired result.  A sample numerical result is

```
SeedRandom[1066];
test = Thread[{K1, K2, K3, C , W} -> RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 5]]
(* {K1 -> -0.198869, K2 -> -1.87425, K3 -> -0.429646, C -> -2.69173, W -> 0.774499} *)
sh /. test
Replace[sabcd /. test, List /@ %, Infinity]
(* {h -> -0.868514, h -> 0.118971, h -> 2.95534, 
    h -> 0.342404 - 0.537515 I, h -> 0.342404 + 0.537515 I} *)
(* {{a -> -0.334413, b -> -0.676002, c -> -0.313254, d -> -1.36807}, 
    {a -> -3.68652, b -> 1.02082, c -> -0.0647982, d -> 0.0387649}, 
    {a -> 0.0172311, b -> -0.118525, c -> 0.186891, d -> -2.77733}, 
    {a -> -1.20902 + 0.762827 I, b -> 0.00917872 - 2.12049 I, 
     c -> 0.606457 + 0.390022 I, d -> -2.09835 + 0.967645 I}, 
    {a -> -1.20902 - 0.762827 I, b -> 0.00917872 + 2.12049 I, 
     c -> 0.606457 - 0.390022 I, d -> -2.09835 - 0.967645 I}} *)
```

This numerical result can be verified quite simply, of course, by

```
Sort /@ NSolve[eq /. test, {h, a, b, c, d}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would write this in MMA:

```
eq = {K1 == c*h/d,
   K2 == b*h/c,
   K3 == a*h/b,
   C == a + b + c + d,
   h + d == W/h + b + 2 a
   };
sol=Solve[eq, {h, a, b, c, d}]
```

MMA take severyl hours, but finally we get an output that is too lengthy to display here. I only give the answer for h:

```
h /. sol

{Root[-K1 K2 K3 W + (-2 C K1 K2 K3 - K1 K2 W) #1 + (-C K1 K2 + 
       K1 K2 K3 - K1 W) #1^2 + (K1 K2 - W) #1^3 + (C + 
       K1) #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1], 
 Root[-K1 K2 K3 W + (-2 C K1 K2 K3 - K1 K2 W) #1 + (-C K1 K2 + 
       K1 K2 K3 - K1 W) #1^2 + (K1 K2 - W) #1^3 + (C + 
       K1) #1^4 + #1^5 &, 2], 
 Root[-K1 K2 K3 W + (-2 C K1 K2 K3 - K1 K2 W) #1 + (-C K1 K2 + 
       K1 K2 K3 - K1 W) #1^2 + (K1 K2 - W) #1^3 + (C + 
       K1) #1^4 + #1^5 &, 3], 
 Root[-K1 K2 K3 W + (-2 C K1 K2 K3 - K1 K2 W) #1 + (-C K1 K2 + 
       K1 K2 K3 - K1 W) #1^2 + (K1 K2 - W) #1^3 + (C + 
       K1) #1^4 + #1^5 &, 4], 
 Root[-K1 K2 K3 W + (-2 C K1 K2 K3 - K1 K2 W) #1 + (-C K1 K2 + 
       K1 K2 K3 - K1 W) #1^2 + (K1 K2 - W) #1^3 + (C + 
       K1) #1^4 + #1^5 &, 5]}
```

Comment: Your fourth equation has a lower case $c$ on the left hand side. The OP has an upper case $C$ here.

Comment: @DanielHuber as Conor mentioned, it the C is upper-case in equation 4. Perhaps you could provide the part of the output for one of the variables (just ```h``` for example).

Comment: Hi,made C uppercase. After several hours MMA finally got an answer. I changed my answer and  I duely report the out put for h as the whole output is rather lengthy

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
eqs = {K1 == c*h/d, K2 == b*h/c, K3 == a*h/b, C == a + b + c + d, h + d == W/h + b + 2 a};
Eliminate[eqs,{a,b,c,d}]
```

to get, e.g., the equation for `h`.